# How to make object bend like a hair strand (particle system) - 2.77a?

Tags: particles

First I set up the particle system to work with bending grass and hair dynamics, then I change the hair to an object. The object is a tree I have generated. The wind blows the tree as a whole, but I need the branches and trunk to bend.

Comment: Probably you'll need to set up an armature for that tree.

Comment: @MrZak the problem with that is that armature is not affected by the wind force field.

Answer (score 1):

I will demonstrate only on the trunk, the branches are the same idea.
At first add the cloth simulation and turn on the pinning, then assign the bottom vertices of the trunk to a groop and in the cloth simulation panel under the pinning set to the groop u just made, then use this picture values as a basis to make it suit u own purpose 
[image]